# Hibernate is mapping again all .hbm files in every new tomcat session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on a messy web java project, with hibernate and  tomcat server. First time i deploy the war on the server i can see the following log:

```
...
ContextLoader:273 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started XmlWebApplicationContext:495 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 06 14:18:37 COT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
DefaultListableBeanFactory:557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4fba4e8c: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,jdbcExceptionTranslator,hibernateTemplate,transactionManager,AbstractSpringDao,.......]; root of factory hierarchy
Environment:514 - Hibernate 3.2.5
Environment:547 - hibernate.properties not found
Environment:681 - Bytecode provider name : cglib
Environment:598 - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com...bean1...
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com...bean2...
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com...bean3...
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com...bean4...
...
```

but every time i open the home page on a new browser window.... i see this log:

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext:495 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@4f8e9bee: startup date [Wed Aug 06 14:40:30 COT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from file [/home/david/Documents/INTERKONT/siccu/siente/build/web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
DefaultListableBeanFactory:557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6b8616ff: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,jdbcExceptionTranslator,hibernateTemplate,transactionManager,AbstractSpringDao .......]; root of factory hierarchy
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com....bean1...
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com....bean2...
HbmBinder:300 - Mapping class: co.com....bean3...
...
```

Any ideas????

this is my applicationContext.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
               xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
               xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"       
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

            <!-- DataSource Definition -->
            <bean id="dataSource"
                  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName">
                    <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
                </property>
                <property name="url">
                    <value>jdbc:postgresql:DBDBDBDBDB</value>
                </property>
                <property name="username">
                    <value>XXXX</value>
                </property>
                <property name="password">
                    <value>YYYYYYYY</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory Definition -->
               <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                <property name="mappingResources">
                    <list>


                        <value>co/com/....bean1.hbm.xml</value>
                        <value>co/com/....bean2.hbm.xml</value>
                        <value>co/com/....bean3.hbm.xml</value>
                        ...
                        ...



                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
                <property name="dataSource">
                    <ref bean="dataSource" />
                </property>
            </bean>
    <!-- Spring Data Access Exception Translator Defintion -->
        <bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- Hibernate Template Defintion -->
        <bean id="hibernateTemplate"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
            <property name="jdbcExceptionTranslator">
                <ref bean="jdbcExceptionTranslator" />
            </property>
        </bean><!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref local="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
        </bean>
       <bean id="AbstractSpringDao" abstract="true" class="cobra.dao.AbstractSpringDao" scope="prototype">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate">
            <ref bean="hibernateTemplate" />
        </property>
       </bean>
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Provide the method where you have configured Hibernate to load your mappings.

Comment: Ok, how do you inject or retrieve this sessionFactory bean?

Comment: Are you reloading the application context with every request? Or do you just observe hibernate mapping files get reloaded?

Comment: Sorry guys, i am a newbie... all i can see is getHibernateTemplate() everywhere in AbstractSpringDao.java

Comment: @DavidValdivieso you have to locate where the spring context is laoaded. It probably is something like `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");` This should happen only one time for the lifetime of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are creating application context in your controller.

move this code outside of the controller.

> ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");

and configure in your web.xml similer to below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. The web.xml was ok, but someone for some reason put new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"); inside home controller bean...

Answer (score 0):

In the first block off log lines, you see the correct way to configure spring in a web application: the context is loaded through the ContextLoader either from a listener or from a (Dispatcher)Servlet.

In the second block, the same application context is loaded again directly from disk. This is not correct.

The second load probably happens in a Servlet.service(...) method.

Instead of reloading the application context on every request, you could use WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext()); to access the one loaded previously.

This is not the preferred way to use spring in a web application (You should read about spring web), but it is probably the easiest way to fix your setup.